# Fatal error: dos/dos.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, dos

Trying to build an app "with NDK", but get an error:

```
D:\AndroidProjects\SampleProject\Jmaster\src\main\jni\expat-2.0.1\amiga\expat_lib.c:24:21: fatal error: dos/dos.h: No such file or directory
make.exe: *** [D:\AndroidProjects\SampleProject\Jmaster\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/DeflatingDecompressor-v3/D_\AndroidProjects\SampleProject\Jmaster\src\main\jni\expat-2.0.1\amiga\expat_lib.o] Error 1
#include <dos/dos.h>
compilation terminated.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It doesn't sound like that library has been set up to be built for Android.

Comment: Once I found a solution to this problem, but now I can't remember what. ;(